# Getting the tags from a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, git-tag

In a project in my GitHub repository I've been tagging the project and pushing the tags:

```
git push --tags
```

The tags appear correctly in the GitHub repository, however I work with this project in different machines, and in some machines I lack some of the tags.

But if I make a git pull:

```
git pull origin master
```

The code is updated but the tags are not, meaning I only have the tags created on that machine and I don't get the rest from GitHub.

How can I get all the tags from GitHub into my local repository?

Comment: have you tried `git pull --tags` ?

Comment: It makes sense and it works, I don't know how it didn't occurred to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fetch from a remote it should bring with it the tags. But only if they're [pointing to objects tracked from branch heads](http://gitref.org/branching/#tag).

To explicitly grab all tags, no matter if they're not reachable from a branch head or not, you'll need to use the `--tags` flag.

```
git fetch origin --tags
```

The above will pull down all tags that are on the origin repo.